# What to do when pandas column renaming creates column name duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

Why doesn't a `pandas.DataFrame` object complain when I rename a column if the new column name already exists?

This makes referencing the new column in the future return a pandas.DataFrame as opposed to a pandas.Series , which can cause further errors.

Secondly, is there a suggested way to handle such a situation?

Example:

```
import pandas

df = pd.DataFrame( {'A' : ['foo','bar'] ,'B'  : ['bar','foo'] } )
df.B.map( {'bar':'foo','foo':'bar'} )
# 0    foo
# 1    bar
# Name: B, dtype: object

df.rename(columns={'A':'B'},inplace=True)
```

Now, the following will fail:

```
df.B.map( {'bar':'foo','foo':'bar'} )
#AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Comment: Well you could just test whether the new name already exists in your df before renaming something like `d={'A':'B'} if df.columns.isin(d.values()).any() == False: df,rename(columns=d, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you had a dictionary mapping old columns to new column names.  When renaming your DataFrame, you could use a dictionary comprehension to test if the new value `v` is already in the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
d = {'a': 'B', 'b': 'B'}
df.rename(columns={k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if v not in df}, inplace=True)
>>> df
    a   B
0   1   3
1   2   4

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
d = {'a': 'b'}
df.rename(columns={k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if v not in df}, inplace=True)
>>> df
    a   b
0   1   3
1   2   4
```